# What are 'MUST' test cases to test Push Notification for Android app?

Tags: android

I am testing Android app which has Push Notification functionality. Could anybody tell what are those test cases that must be tested for Push Notifications?

Android does NOT have Notification Center kind of thing so what different scenarios should be tested for Push Notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many but the major are :

1. To check if the notification received even if the app is not running
2. Check if the notification received if the app was open, or during playing a game, or using another app.
3. Check if the notification received on multiple time zones .
4. Is it clickable? If it is, what should it do? Open the app or open a new activity?

I think these are the most important, unless you have some other specifications your would like to add to your question.

Comment: Are those implementation depended? I have the feeling most are handled by Android it self.

Comment: Niels' question comes also in my mind, when I think about sound, vibration, blinking and the iOS Notification Center. Do we test the application or the OS, when we test that? Our decision was to test these things too. Just to be sure.

Comment: the time zones case is server side issue it has nothing to so with android, case number 4 is completely implementation depended and the other 2 yes they are OS depended but who the app would handle them is an implementation issue. @NielsvanReijmersdal

Answer (score 9):

Here are some Test cases

- Verify the notification received even if the app is open.
- Verify the notification received even if the app is closed.
- Verify the notification received even if the device is lock.
- Verify the notification received even if user playing the game.
- Verify the notification received even if another app is in use.
- Verify the notification received in multiple time zones.
- Verify the notification is clickable & it's open up the notification.
- Verify the sound, vibration & blinking.
- Verify the notification when the user is not SignIn.
- Verify the notification should get removed from notification bar once the notification is opened.
- Verify when the notification comes & device is locked, if the user opens the device with sliding the notification then the application should get launched & navigate to that specific notification (App in the background).
- Verify when the notification comes in the foreground, then the notification will display directly on the app (App in foreground).
- Verify repeated notification multiple times and check notification is in the order.
- Verify recent notification message always should be on the top in a stack.
- Verify when the user didn't click on a banner then the notification count should get updated on the icon of the application.
- Verify prevent repeating the same notification over and over again by the possible triggers.

Answer (score 3):

[The Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) has a lot of different features. An example is the "[Setting an Expiration Date for a Message](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#ttl)" feature, here you want to test the notification is removed after a X period.

So it really depends on what features have been implemented by the development team, do not test feature that are "free" of the operating system and that you would expect to always work.

The **must test feature** is *end-to-end notification delivery*, trigger message somewhere and receiving on the correct device.

Other features that come to mind:

- The entry point in the application, for example when you open an IM (WhatsApp, Skype, etc) notification it opens the sending user and last message send to you and not the start (user-list) screen.
- Prevent repeating the same notification over and over again by the possible triggers

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if Push Message is received when Device is locked.
2. Check that the notification received even if the app is not running.
3. Check that the notification received if the app was open or using another app.
4. Check if the notification received in multiple time zones.
5. Check if the notification is clickable and it launches the application by clicking.
6. Check the push notification sound, vibration.
7. Repeat the notification multiple times and check the push notification displayed in notification bar.
8. In foreground, When notification comes in foreground, then the notification will display directly on the app.
   10.In background: When notification comes & device is locked, if user open the device with sliding the notification then the application should get launched.
9. Notification should get removed from notification bar once the notification is opened.
10. Check the notification when the application is not logged in.
11. Check with multiple device languages.
12. Check whether the notification received when the application comes online.

Answer (score 1):

1.Notification received - when the app is running in foreground.

2.Notification received -  when the app is running in background.

3.Notification received -  when you are in some other screen.

4.Notification received - when app is killed.

5.Notification received -  when app is launched.

6.Check the notification received time.

7.Check the notification received in different time zones.

8.Check when notification received then sound,vibration,Blink.

9.Title of the notification.

10.Check the notification count increase whenever the new notification is received.

11.Check the redirection of the notification.

12.Check the notification status is updated time to time (i.e for eg:- consider the example of taxi booking when driving reaching then update of ETA and arriving status, start and end ride status).

13.Language of notification.

14.When notification received and user didn’t click on bell icon of notification than the count should get updated on the notification icon of the application.

15.When the user read the notification then count should get updated.

16.If the app contain the feature of in-app chat then check the notification is received when the user is receiving any message.

Note :- There can be more than these depends on the conditions and requirement from clients.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify if the app works on mobile data
2. Verify receiving notifications with the same users connected to multiple devices

Answer (score 0):

1. Test if Push Message is received when Device is locked.
   Preconditions: App is Closed
2. Test if Push Message is received when Device is locked.
   Preconditions: App is in Background.
3. Test if Push Message is received.
   Preconditions: App is in use.
4. Test if Push Message is received.
   Preconditions: App is Closed
5. Test if Push Message is received.when other app is in use.
   Preconditions: App is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the good answers above, but don't forget to ask you customers, developers, architects or sells people.

And as always go over [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf).

Some examples could be- existing bugs, standards, data about usage and issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

Notification tifications should get to ushould be update everytime. Example:- Notificaton is display in event cooming soon in 12 days. The every day the day are auto change and notifications should get.

If user 1 send multiple notifications to same user2.
If user2 click on any notification then all notification should be clear from mobile notification screen.
If user get notifications and user open notification in different time then in message should be display exact nottifcation time.
If Admin send notification from CMS or One signal then notification should get to user.
If internet is disconnect then notification should not get.
If User start Internet then all notifications shoud get.
If screen is lock then notifications should get.
If phon is switch off, then after restart phon then notification should get ( internet on)
If user clicks on notifications then page should be redirect to realted page.
If admin send notification to different country, locations & time then notifications should get to every user same time.
If internet is down the notifications should get. (check time)
if the notification received even if the app is not running notification received even if the app is open.
Notifications should get if user playing the game.
Notifications should get in any time zone.
Notifications should receive in sound,silent,vibrate mode.
Notifications should not get if user not SignIn.
If app is logout & user get notitfication then on clicking notifications then page should be redirect to login page.
The notification comes & device is locked, if the user opens the device with sliding the notification then the application should get launched & navigate to that specific notification (App in the background).
The notification comes in the foreground, then the notification will display directly on the app (App in foreground).
Repeated notifications should get in order/sequences.
Recent notification message always should be in top in notifications bar.
If the notifications icon is change the updated icon should be display in notifications.
If artist send msg in groups then notification time should be same.
If fans get lots notifications of different artist then in notifications should display name of artist.
If artist organise event for fans then notifications should be get to all selected fans.
If user purchase for user2 then notifications should get.
If user renew the plan then noser2.