# What are the Test Cases for Push Notification?

Tags: automated-testing

Here are some cases I need to test:

1. Same user login on multiple Android Devices?
2. Different user login on multiple Android Devices?
3. No user login on Android Devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are 'MUST' test cases to test Push Notification for Android app?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8908/what-are-must-test-cases-to-test-push-notification-for-android-app)

Comment: I'm not really seeing a question here. Jay, could you describe what your situation is, and what you've done for test cases thus far?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few General Test cases for Push notification functionality, you can relate these test cases to your mobile application.

- Verify the notification received even if the app is open.
- Verify the notification received even if the app is closed.
- Verify the notification received even if the device is locked.
- Verify the notification received even if user playing the game.
- Verify the notification received even if another app is in use.
- Verify the notification received in multiple time zones.
- Verify the notification is clickable & it's open up the notification.
- Verify the sound, vibration & blinking.
- Verify the notification when the user is not SignIn.
- Verify the notification should get removed from notification bar once
  the notification is opened.
- Verify when the notification comes & device is locked, if user open
  the device with sliding the notification then the application should get launched & navigate to that specific notification (App in the background).
- Verify when notification comes in foreground, then the notification
  will display directly on the app (App in foreground).
- Verify repeated notification multiple times and check notification is
  in the order.
- Verify recent notification message always should be on the top in
  stack.
- Verify when user didn't click on a banner then the notification count
  should get updated on the icon of the application.
- Verify prevent repeating the same notification over and over again by
  the possible triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe a little bit more the context and the application?

You can check multiples sessions of the same account yes on two devices, app in background, app stopped and these two operations again after you logged out the current session and ensure that you don't receive them in this case.

Comment: this Application is related to Medical.

Suppose there are multiple clinician login on mobile devices. and Physician can fill out form and click on submit button then notification goes on that devices.